# Supress formatting after @copybrief

Tags: formatting, doxygen

Using doxygen version 1.8.16

When I pull in comments for a function like this

CameraScript.Start() @copybrief CameraScript.Start()

Doxygen adds an extra paragraph tag

```
<p><a class="el" href="class_camera_script.html#a73f305dadb9b5b88d6efcc80a9073710" title="Use this for initialization">CameraScript.Start()</a> </p>
<p>Use this for initialization <br  />
</p>
```

Resulting in output like this

```
CameraScript.Start()

Use this for initialization
```

How do I suppress this and include the text as part of the function text so it turns out like this

```
<p><a class="el" href="class_camera_script.html#a73f305dadb9b5b88d6efcc80a9073710" title="Use this for initialization">CameraScript.Start()</a> <br  />
Use this for initialization <br  /> </p>
```

I would like output like this

```
CameraScript.Start()
Use this for initialization
```

Edit: Add simple example - make foo.md the main page.

foo.cs

```
public class foo
{
   /// <summary>
   /// This is my comment. I do not want the space above it
   /// </summary>
   public void foobar()
   {
       Debug.Log("Foo");
   }
}
```

foo.md

```
foo.foobar() @copybrief foo.foobar()
```

Produces

foo.foobar()

This is my comment. I do not want the space above it

Comment: Welcome. Which version of doxygen are you using? On which page do you see the problem? A [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would help as well.

Comment: updated with example and doxygen version info as requested

Comment: I see what you mean. The closest I can get is using `\brief` instead of `<summary>`. Although the documentation says:"<summary> Identifies the brief description. Similar to using \brief." there is apparently  difference between `\brief` and `<summary>`

Comment: I found one alternative which I will use for now but it limits me to only one line for a comment unless i embed a second return. Also any other comment lines above or below this line causes nothing to appear at all


 /// \n Comment 1st line

Comment: I checked against the current doxygen version (1.9.6) and here the problem is not present anymore.